# inverse of the normalized duality mapping

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

in Fixed point theory, Let X be a normed space and $\mu$ a gauge function. Then the mapping $ J_{\mu}:X\longrightarrow {2^{X^*}}$ defined by

$$J_{\mu}(x)=\{j\in X^*: (x,j)=\|x\|\|j\|_*,  \|j\|_*=(\mu(\|x\|)\}$$

is called the duality mapping with gauge function $\mu$.

**Now, Let X be a reflexive Banach space and $J^*:X^*\longrightarrow X$ the
inverse of the normalized duality mapping $J:X\longrightarrow X^*$ Then 
$$J^*J=I , JJ^*=I$$**
where 
$$J^*(j)=J^{-1}(j)=\{x\in X: (x,j)=\|x\|\|j\|_*,  \|x\|=(\mu^{-1}(\|j\|_*)\}$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: See page 76 of the book of "Fixed point Theory for Lipschitzian-type mapping with Applications" by "Ravi P.Agarwal"